# Can't read properties file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, properties, stream, classpath

The following JUnit test is working in my application:

```
@Test
public void testMessageResources(){
    final InputStream stream = getClass().
        getResourceAsStream("/com/service/MessageResources.properties");
    Assert.assertNotNull(stream);
}
```

But in my JSP, I can't read the file using this code:

```
<%
    final InputStream resourceAsStream = application.
        getResourceAsStream("/com/service/MessageResources.properties");
%>
```

`resourceAsStream` is always `null`. I'm using JSP 2.1.

---

The `MessageResources.properties` file is on the classpath, but **not** inside the JSP directory. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSP uses [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), which doesn't do the same thing as `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. It doesn't search for the resources in the classpath. If you want to use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`, then use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. It will also work in a Java EE context. Just make sure to use a class loaded from the same classloader as the one you want to use to load your properties file.

Such a method call shouldn't be done in a JSP, though, but in a Servlet or action which forxards to the JSP. JSPs should be used to generate markup.

Answer (score 1):

The getClass().getResourceAsStream() searches the file in the classpath, while application.getResourceAsStream looks for the resource in your web application directly. So the directory 'com' should be inside your web application and not in the classpath.